# colSums in R: 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, sum

I am a beginner in coding in general. I am trying to calculate two parameters from a data frame named `a` in R. For row i and column j, I am interested in finding:

B = (sum of all values in column j) - a[i,j]

C = (sum of all values in row i) - a[i,j]

For i=1 , j=2, I'm writing:

```
  A = a[1,2]
  B = (colSums(a[1:nrow(a),1],na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1) - A)
  C = (rowSums(a[1,1:ncol(a)],na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1) - A)
```

C seems to give correct answer. However, B gives an error:

```
Error in base::colSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

I have read other threads as well but couldn't find my answer. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think that the problem is because you have only one column, and `colSums()` is applied to matrices with more than one column. In that case, what you want is to use `a[1:nrow(a),1]` which is the same as `a[,1]` because you are selecting all the rows.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is due to the command `a[1:nrow(a),1]`. This command selects all rows of the first column of data frame `a` *but* returns the result as a vector (not a data frame). The function `colSums` does not work with one-dimensional objects (like vectors).

As a side note: You don't need `1:nrow(a)` to select all rows. The same is easier to achieve with an empty argument before the comma: `a[ , 1]`.

An example data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)
#   a b
# 1 1 4
# 2 2 5
# 3 3 6
```

If you select one column, the result is converted into a vector automatically.

```
dat[ , 1]
# [1] 1 2 3
```

If you specify `drop = FALSE`, a one-column data frame is returned.

```
dat[ , 1, drop = FALSE]
#   a
# 1 1
# 2 2
# 3 3
```

This one-column data frame is a two-dimensional object and can therefore be used with `colSums`.

```
colSums(dat[ , 1, drop = FALSE])
# a 
# 6
```